# why flask_login does not store authentication in my program?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

i am programming by flask and i have a problem with flask_login
login and authentication will complete when i enter username and password and i can get my user data in login page but after redirecting to other pages the user become anonymous! it seems that flask_login or UserMixin module does not work correctly. Please help me to solve this problem in my code

```
    app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'



@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = Models.DATABASE
    g.db.connect()
    g.user=current_user

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(useremail):
    try:
        return Models.User.select().where(
            Models.User.email == str(useremail)
        ).get()
    except  Models.DoesNotExist:
        return None
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
g.db.close()
return response

@app.route('/login', methods=('GET','POST'))
def login():

form=forms.Signinform()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    try:
        user = Models.User.get(
            Models.User.email == form.email.data
        )
        if (user.password==hashmypassword(form.password.data)):
            login_user(user)
            flash("You're now logged in!")
            print(user.join_date)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            
            flash("No user with that email/password combo")
            print(hashmypassword(form.password.data))
            print(form.password.data)
            return redirect(url_for('register'))
    except Models.DoesNotExist:
          
          flash("No user with that email/password combo")
    except:
        print(user.password)
        flash ("incorrect")
        
return render_template('login.html',form=form)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():

if current_user.is_authenticated:
    print(current_user.email)
else:
    print("No AAA")
"""Renders the home page."""
return render_template(
    'index.html',
    title='Home Page',
    year=datetime.datetime.now().year,
)
```

i am authenticated in login page but not authenticated in home page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem solved using these functions in my Model class

```
def is_active(self):
    """True, as all users are active."""
    return True

def get_id(self):
    """Return the email address to satisfy Flask-Login's requirements."""
    return self.email

def is_authenticated(self):
    """Return True if the user is authenticated."""
    return self.authenticated

def is_anonymous(self):
    """False, as anonymous users aren't supported."""
    return False
```

i thought that def is_authenticated(self) is enough but all of these functions was necessary

Answer (score 0):

Use the tag `@login_required` in your other functions in routes like this,

```
@app.route('/login', methods=('GET','POST'))
@login_required
def login():

form=forms.Signinform()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    try:
        user = Models.User.get(
            Models.User.email == form.email.data
        )
        if (user.password==hashmypassword(form.password.data)):
            login_user(user)
            flash("You're now logged in!")
            print(user.join_date)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            
            flash("No user with that email/password combo")
            print(hashmypassword(form.password.data))
            print(form.password.data)
            return redirect(url_for('register'))
    except Models.DoesNotExist:
          
          flash("No user with that email/password combo")
    except:
        print(user.password)
        flash ("incorrect")
        
return render_template('login.html',form=form)
```

Comment: Thanks but what should i do if i wanna use my home page for both anonymous and logged in users? i dont want to force them to login

Comment: Then dont use this tag on the functions you want to use for anonymous users. Like if you want a login form to appear for anonymous users, then dont use this tag for the login function. But if you want a particular function to be used only when a person is logged in, use this tag.

Comment: it did not solve my problem . when i am in login page  i am authorized . i have commented this line to find out this : return redirect(url_for('home'))    but after redirecting to login page it is anonymous. and when i added @login_required the problem did not solve

Comment: Define the home function in the routes.py file and add the login required tag, It will work. If not, consider going through the following article: <https://realpython.com/using-flask-login-for-user-management-with-flask/>

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by storing authentication?
By your question, if you want to identify logged in users, using flask-session is a good option. You can find the documentation here: https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

When a user logs in, you may create session variables as:

```
session['id'] = user_id
session['username'] = username
session['loggedin'] = true
```

Then you may specifically include in your routes what do you want for logged in users:

```
if 'loggedin' in session: 
     do this
else:
     do that
```

You may also access these session variables in any route.

Comment: The problem is exactly not accessing to these sessions in other routes! when i return to my homepage the user is anonymous !